# Как сократить частоту появления капч для selenium в Яндекс.Недвижимости?

Tags: selenium, captcha, puppeteer

В общем, проблема состоит в том, что, используя selenium, при первом же driver.get() на сайт Яндекс.Недвижимость вылезает капча. После прохождения капчи она вылезает снова на 2-м запросе. С обычного браузера все работает отлично. Как скрыть от яндекса selenium или хотя бы сильно сократить частоту капч?

Comment: На всякий случай уточню, user-agent указан, а капча вылезает только после полной загрузки страницы (т.е предположительно после выполнения какого-то js кода)

Comment: Аналогично, хром в режиме инкогнито при поиске в гугле сразу подсовывает свою рекаптчу. Правда, только один раз. Предполагаю, что может быть причина в fingerprint браузера. Я бы посмотрел на трафик. Он зашифрован? Да. Используйте Kalilinux, там есть промежуточный сертификат, который используется в MITM. Можно будет сравнить, что гоняется в том и другом случае.

Comment: как вариант, попробуйте вначале зайти через селениум в яндекс почту, например, с этого получити их куки для `.yandex.ru`, с которыми уже идите на свою недвижимость

Comment: Попробуйте использовать uBlock Origin или подобный блокировщик. Вместе с рекламой они порежут телеметрию и библиотеки фингерпринтинга, так что это может сработать.

Comment: uBlock Origin + Яндекс.Почта работают (частично), но, к сожалению, я могу запускать только headless chrome на сервере, одна лишь яндекс.почта с капчей не справляется

Comment: Условно считаем, что причина - фингерпринт. У безголового хромого функционал очень кастрирован. Логично, что у вас осталось два варианта: вмешиваться в траффик, либо запускать полную версию. В первом случае - используйте прокси + MITM. Еще вот что нашел https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/ и https://antoinevastel.com/bot%20detection/2018/01/17/detect-chrome-headless-v2.html

Comment: Chrome в данной ситауации слабое звено, но! у вас есть возможность использовать полнофункциональный Firefox в headless режиме, и там же с ним и uBlock Origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox + uBlock Origin действительно решение моей проблемы, все работает отлично!

Comment: Google Chrome + uBlock Origin так же работает без пока вроде проблем =)

Comment: Да, только работа нужна в headless режиме, хром в этом режиме с расширениями не работает